# Sony SpresenseでAdafruit NeoPixelを制御する方法について

Tags: spresense

Spresenseのデモを展示しているソニーさんのブースでLEDパネルをアニメーションさせているもの(https://twitter.com/make/status/1130204040610979840 の冒頭に映っています)があり、
これと同じようなことを自分もやってみたいと思い

- Sony Spresenseメインボード
- Sony Spresense拡張ボード
- Quimat Arduino用RGBLEDパネル 256ピクセル QWS03

などを組み合わせた回路を制作し
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel
↑こちらのライブラリのデモを試しに動かしてみたのですが、うまく動作しませんでした。

Arduino(Genuino)101で全く同じ回路とピンの刺し方で試したところ正常に動作したので、
上記のライブラリがSpresenseに対応していないと思われるのですが、
Spresenseに対応したNeoPixelのライブラリはどこかで配布されているのでしょうか？
配布されていない場合、既存のNeoPixelライブラリのコードの
どの部分を改変すれば動作させられるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

Spresense用のライブラリを見つけました。
https://github.com/hideakitai/SpresenseNeoPixel
ソニーさんがこれを使っているのかどうかは分かりませんが参考になれば。